# Resolve error "Instance member 'signIn' can't be accessed using static access."

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a class  called GoogleAuthApi that I am trying to call within a function, sendNewUserEmail, inside the _UserProfileScreenState class. All of the necessary code is below.

However, I am getting an error when calling the GoogleAuthApi.signIn function where I am trying to see if the current user is signed into their google account. The error code is tagged on the signIn part. Here is the error message:

```
Instance member 'signIn' can't be accessed using static access.
```

How do I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
class UserProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'user_profile_screen';
  final Users? users;
  final bool? isNewUser;

  const UserProfileScreen([this.isNewUser, this.users]);

  @override
  ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> createState() => _UserProfileScreenState();
}

class _UserProfileScreenState extends ConsumerState<UserProfileScreen> {
.
.
.
  Future sendNewUserEmail() async {
    final googleUser = await GoogleAuthApi.signIn;
    final accessToken = '';

    final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2('myemail@gmail.com', accessToken);
    final message = Message()
      ..from = const Address("senderemail@gmail.com", "Deal Diligence")
      ..recipients = ['recipient@gmail.com']
      ..subject = "Welcome to Deal Diligence"
      ..text = "Welcome to Deal Diligence. Your password is NewPassword";

    try {
      await send(message, smtpServer);

      //showSnackBar('Invitation email successfully sent');
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
.
.
.
}

class GoogleAuthApi {
  final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    if (_googleSignIn.isSignedIn == true) {
      return _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    } else {
      return await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `signIn` method is not a static method: you need to create an instance of the `GoogleAuthApi` class, or try using `GoogleAuthApi().signIn()`.

```
Future sendNewUserEmail() async {
    final api = GoogleAuthApi();
    final googleUser = await api.signIn;
    final accessToken = '';
...
```